# getting a column value from table as keys in result from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table structure as -

```
name     grade
  a        10
  b        8
  c        9
```

I am writing a query for selecting rows where grade is more than 7, and want the result in this format

```
{
  a: {grade: 10},
  b: {grade: 8},
  c: {grade: 9}
}
```

here is my query

```
     createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('x.name, x.grade as grade')
        ->from('gradesTable', 'x')
        ->where('x.grade > :threshold')
        ->setParameter('threshold', 7)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Which doctrine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'from' function has a third parameter called indexBy. Tha is what you are looking for. Your query should look something like this.

```
....->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('x.name, x.grade as grade')
    ->from('gradesTable', 'x', 'x.name')
    ->where('x.grade > :threshold')
    ->setParameter('threshold', 7)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

And the result will be something like this

```
{
  a: {name: a, grade: 10},
  b: {name: b, grade: 8},
  c: {name: c, grade: 9}
}
```

Don't remove the name from the query. It will not work if you don't select it.
Hope this helps.

Happy coding,

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: Didn't know about the third arg indeed, it also work in the `createQueryBuilder` function. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('x.name, x.grade as grade')
    ->from('gradesTable', 'x')
    ->where('x.grade > :threshold')
    ->setParameter('threshold', 7)
    ->indexBy('x', 'x.name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Or:

```
createQueryBuilder('gradesTable', 'x', 'x.name')
    ->select('x.name, x.grade as grade')
    ->where('x.grade > :threshold')
    ->setParameter('threshold', 7)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

(or accepted answer :) )

When using the `createQuery()` function you can also use:

```
createQuery('SELECT x.name, x.grade as grade FROM gradesTable x INDEX BY x.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's concat function to produce the desired output, e.g.:

```
select concat (name, ": {grade:", grade, "}")
from test 
where grade > 8;
```